# How we can implement a periodic gauge in numerical calculations?

Tags: computational-physics, topological-phase

For a 1D system, there is a way to calculate the **Zak phase** in the discrete form. Suppose *C* is some closed path in k-space (a *1D BZ*). If we suppose the path is discretized into (not necessarily equidistant) k*i* steps with i=1,…,N and k*N+1*≡k*1*, the end result is:

[image]

You can view this as the product (i.e. phase summation) of N small rotations of the eigenvector's phase as it's transported along *C*; the Im(log)-part merely picks out the phase.

If *C* is a non-contractible path in the BZ along a reciprocal lattice vector **G**, it is desirable to enforce a **periodic gauge**, in which case one would take:

[image]

***How we can implement the periodic gauge in numerical calculations***? We know it is necessary when we talk about the berry phase.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I mean how I can do a numerical calculation for considering periodic gauge mentioned above.